# Angular Component reloads after navigating away from page

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular5

**Setup**

Lazy loaded app routing defined in app.routing.ts
Sample code snippet:

```
{
    path: 'contacts',
    children: [{
        path: '',
        loadChildren:'./modules/contacts/contacts.module#ContactsModule'
    }, {
        path: 'contact_type_1',
        loadChildren: './modules/contact-types/type_1/type_1.module#Type1Module',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    }]
}
```

I have a list of contacts. On click I pass contact_type and contact_id to routes like:  `this.router.navigate(['contacts/' + contact_type], { queryParams: { id: contact_id }});`

This loads the respective component for every contact_type and fetches contact data from the server using the contact_id passed.

There's a `ContactGuard` class added to the contact_type route which calls canActivate() to check if the user has the contact with the provided contact_id added in his/her account. If not navigate to contacts list page.

Things work fine so far.

Now clicking on back button takes me to the contacts list page: `routerLink="/contacts"`

**What Happens**

Here, the navigation happens correctly, `ngOnDestroy()` of the contact_type component is also called. But the contact_type component entirely reloads on the contacts list page.

**Expected Behaviour**

On navigating back to the contacts list page the contact_type component should NOT reload. Only the component for contacts list page must be called.

Angular version: 5.2.9

Comment: Can you share some code on stackblitz.com ?

Comment: You can't have two components in the same router outlet, so, when the route changes, the current component is destroyed (and so `ngOnDestroy` is called), then, once you go back by pressing the back button, the component must be reloaded.

Comment: Oh thanks. Can you please help me with how to reload a component? Without having to refresh the entire page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by unsubscribing to `queryParams()` inside `ngOnDestroy()`

Problem was: subscription to `queryParam()` used to get contact_id from URL did not unsubscribe when the component was destroyed. Hence on route change, the subscription was called again.